# Batch script to show multiple filenames in one call

Tags: command-line, batch-file, filenames

Im trying to create a batch script to call a .exe to carry out analysis on multiple data files in a same folder. The syntax should be like:

```
"D:\Softwares\Analyzer.exe" [DataFile1].dat [DataFile2].dat ... [DataFileN].dat AnalysisFile.pdo"
```

Currently I have tried to use a `FOR` loop to scan each *.dat file in a specified folder. (I don't know how many data files in that folder, so I cannot type the filenames directly in the command line)  
  
For example:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /r %%i in (*.dat) DO (
"D:\Softwares\Analyzer.exe" %%~ni.dat TestAnalysis.pdo
)
PAUSE
```

However, the analysis is carried out on seperate datafiles, and the .exe file will pop-up and open every time when a new .dat file is detected. Is there any way I could use `*.dat` or any other methods to represent  *[DataFile1].dat [DataFile2].dat ... [DataFileN].dat* in one line seperated by a space (not a new line)?  
  
I have also tried to use `@tilte`, which does not work as well. Since the .exe window keep pop-up whenever a new .dat file is detected and I have to close each of them in order to continue to next .dat file.
  
  
In general, I would like to do an automatic scan in a folder, get the names of the datafiles, and write a command line to call these .dat files in one line.

Any ideas/helps appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, remove the word `echo` if the output is OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line="
for %%i in (*.dat) do set "line=!line! "%%i""
echo "D:\Softwares\Analyzer.exe" %line% TestAnalysis.pdo
```

The code doesn't work with *dat files with exclams `!` in the file name. This may be fixed if needed.